# Ranking in a new dataframe column based on variable and timestamp

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp, ranking

I have the following dataframe. I want to rank per SalesPerson the transaction timestamps on ascending order and assign them a rank number in a new column

```
    dfxx = pd.DataFrame([['2022-02-09 14:00:22', 'A',''], ['2021-10-03 16:58:07', 'B',''], ['2022-01-31 12:24:12', 'X',''],
                         ['2022-01-31 12:24:18', 'X',''], ['2022-01-31 12:24:15', 'X',''], ['2021-10-03 16:58:09', 'B','']], columns=['Transactiontime', 'SalesPerson','Rank'])
```

|  | Transactiontime | SalesPerson | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-02-09 14:00:22 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-10-03 16:58:07 | B | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-31 12:24:12 | X | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-31 12:24:18 | X | 3 |
| 4 | 2022-01-31 12:24:15 | X | 2 |
| 5 | 2021-10-03 16:58:09 | B | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
dfxx['rank'] = dfxx.groupby('SalesPerson')['Transactiontime'].rank()
```

Output `dfxx`:

```
       Transactiontime SalesPerson Rank  rank
0  2022-02-09 14:00:22           A        1.0
1  2021-10-03 16:58:07           B        1.0
2  2022-01-31 12:24:12           X        1.0
3  2022-01-31 12:24:18           X        3.0
4  2022-01-31 12:24:15           X        2.0
5  2021-10-03 16:58:09           B        2.0
```